# How to access html of after opening webpage with webbrowser

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

I was wondering if it possible to access the html or body of a webpage after opening one using the webbrowser library?

```
import webbrowser

url = "https://testwebsite.com/"
chromePath = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s"
testing = webbrowser.get(chromePath).open(url)
print(testing)
```

This works and gets to the webpage, but prints out True/False since it is a bool. Is there anyway to make it print out the html or body of that website?

Comment: Why do you want to get the HTML? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: try beautiful soup.

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank because I would like to put the text into a file.

Comment: "The text" is what exactly? The complete HTML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I download a file over HTTP using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python)

Answer (score -1):

To get the content of the webpage in python you can use `urllib`.

```
import urllib
googleContent = urllib.urlopen("http://google.com").read()
```

will save the content of `google.com` in the variable `googleContent`.